# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I want to convert my .py file to .exe using **PyInstller.**
I used to do this easily in the past, but now when I enter the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole -icon myiconfile.ico mypythonfile.py
```

This goes well:

```
363 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
364 INFO: Python: 3.9.4
369 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
372 INFO: wrote mypythonfile.spec
380 INFO: UPX is not available.
385 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop',
 'path of project']
1000 INFO: checking Analysis
1002 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1005 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1013 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1030 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
8400 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'path of project\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
8403 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
16265 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
16787 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
16799 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
16952 INFO: Analyzing myiconfile.ico
```

But next i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "path of project\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "path of project\mypythonfile.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['myiconfile', 'mypythonfile'],
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 439, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 265, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "path of project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1419, in add_script
    contents = fp.read() + '\n'
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 30: invalid start byte
```

I searched a lot to solve this problem but none of them were suitable !!
[This is my project](https://github.com/AbRamazani/mahab)
*thanks for answer...*